# Change URL ending with Query String

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I've been using a set of redirect rules for a while that have been working perfectly.

I've recently expanded a part of my website and need to change the ending of a certain URL.

**Old URL:** /clan/{query-string}/tracking/war

**New URL:** /clan/{query-string}/tracking/warlog

I've changed my .htaccess file so the new URL works, but I need the old URL to redirect to the new one.

Currently, this is how I'm redirecting in .htaccess:

```
# Rewrite Clan Tracking-Warlog URL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /clanTracking_main.php\?name=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ /clan/%1/tracking/warlog [L,R]
RewriteRule ^clan/([^/]+)/tracking/warlog clanTracking_main.php?name=$1 [L]
```

It works perfectly but I just need help with the redirection.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the first rule below is what you ask...

I also made some other modifications which appeared to make sense to me...

```
# Rewrite Clan Tracking-Warlog URL
RewriteEngine On

# redirect old to new
RewriteRule ^/?clan/([^/]+)/tracking/war$ /clan/$1/tracking/warlog [R=301]

# pick name from get argument and redirect
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)name=([^\s]+)(?:&) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?clanTracking_main\.php$ /clan/%1/tracking/warlog [R=301]

# rewrite to php
RewriteRule ^/?clan/([^/]+)/tracking/warlog$ clanTracking_main.php?name=$1 [END]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Well it worked on my testing subdomain but now that I've implemented on my main site, it's no longer working..

Any idea why that would be?

Comment: UPDATE: I played around with it and once I added L inside the ending brackets, it started working. I'm not an expert so I have no clue why it works that way and not the other so if anybody could explain that, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: The `L` flag cannot make any difference here... The `END` flag beats that one and the `R` flags terminate the process anyway. In which directive did you add that flag? And did you really use exactly the suggestion I posted above or something modified?